# SQL Server - Delete unused rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to get stored procedure (not standart, only custom) to delete unused rows table (table1) and some other tables (table2, table3, table4...- **we don't know how many tables refers to table1 by FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT**) can refers to this table.

For example:

```
СREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[delete_on_constraints]
@table varchar(36) – table name we need to delete unused rows
@column varchar(36) – column name - primary key, on which other tables refers by FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT
```

There are the table1 and table2, table3 which  refers to  table1 (remind, we don't know how many tables refers to table1 by FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT)

```
CREATE TABLE [table1] (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_ table1] PRIMARY KEY,
    [value] [int] NULL 
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [table2] (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_ table2] PRIMARY KEY,
    [table1_id] [int] NOT NULL ,
       CONSTRAINT [FK_ table2_ table1] FOREIGN KEY ([table1_id]) REFERENCES [table1] ( [id] ) 
) 
GO 

CREATE TABLE [table3] (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_ table3] PRIMARY KEY,
    [table1_id] [int] NOT NULL ,
       CONSTRAINT [FK_ table3_ table1] FOREIGN KEY ([table1_id]) REFERENCES [table1] ( [id] ) 
)

GO 
INSERT INTO [table1] VALUES (100)
INSERT INTO [table1] VALUES (200)
INSERT INTO [table1] VALUES (300)
INSERT INTO [table1] VALUES (400)

GO
INSERT INTO [table2] VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO [table2] VALUES (3)

GO
INSERT INTO [table3] VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO [table3] VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO [table3] VALUES (3)
```

There are rows in tables **before** call stored procedure

```
table1
id value
1 100
2 200
3 300
4 400

table2
id table1_id
1 1
2 3

table3
id table1_id
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

And **after** [dbo].[delete_on_constraints] ‘table1’ ‘id’ procedure call

```
table1

id       value
1        100
2        200
3        300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me state for the record that this code should never be used in production. By that I mean, it should only ever be used as a one-time cleanup. If you have regular need  of deleting rows without knowing the DRI, then there is a fundamental design problem.

In short, you need to use dynamic SQL to query for the relations and build the Delete statements.

```
Declare @Columns Cursor
Declare @PKTableSchema nvarchar(128)
Declare @PKTableName nvarchar(128)
Declare @PKColumnName nvarchar(128)
Declare @TableSchema nvarchar(128)
Declare @TableName nvarchar(128)
Declare @ColumnName nvarchar(128)
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max)

Set @Columns = Cursor Fast_Forward For
    Select Quotename(PK_CCU.TABLE_SCHEMA)
        , Quotename(PK_CCU.TABLE_NAME)
        , Quotename(PK_CCU.COLUMN_NAME)
        , Quotename(RC_CCU.TABLE_SCHEMA)
        , Quotename(RC_CCU.TABLE_NAME)
        , Quotename(RC_CCU.COLUMN_NAME)
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS As RC
        Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE As RC_CCU
            On RC_CCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                And RC_CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS As TC
            On TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                And TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
                And TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
        Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE As PK_CCU
            On PK_CCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                And PK_CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    Where PK_CCU.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
        And PK_CCU.TABLE_NAME = @TableParam
        And PK_CCU.COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnParam

Open @Columns 
Fetch Next From @Columns Into @PKTableSchema, @PKTableName, @PKColumnName, @TableSchema, @TableName, @ColumnName

Set @Sql = 'Delete ' + @PKTableSchema + '.' + @PKTableName 
    + ' Where 1 = 1' 

While @@Fetch_Status = 0
Begin
    Set @Sql = @Sql + Char(13) + Char(10)
        + ' And Not Exists ( Select 1 From ' + @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName
                            + ' Where ' + @ColumnName + ' = ' + @PKTableSchema + '.' + @PKTableName + '.' + @PKColumnName
                            + ')'
    Fetch Next From @Columns Into @PKTableSchema, @PKTableName, @PKColumnName, @TableSchema, @TableName, @ColumnName
End

Close @Columns
Deallocate @Columns

--Print @Sql
Exec( @Sql )
```

Btw, let me also mention that a better solution might be to enable Cascade Delete on your relations. With cascade delete, the need for this routine would be moot.

See [Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119(SQL.80).aspx) for more.